# Is there any book online that shows mathematical procedures relating to perspective drawing?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

I am trying to learn comprehensive mathematical analyses (rather than geometrical methods) about perspective drawing projections. Can anyone suggest a good online book to buy that illustrates mathematical analyses in detail relating to perspective drawing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Viewpoints: Mathematical Perspective and Fractal Geometry in Art* by by Marc Frantz and Annalisa Crannell:

[http://www.amazon.com/Viewpoints-Mathematical-Perspective-Fractal-Geometry/dp/0691125929](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691125929)